# OS/X Server + Airport Extreme = daily crash

Tags: airport, server.app

I have a 4th generation Airport Extreme acting as the main interface between my network and the internet. I recently installed OS/X Server on one of my machines on the network, during that install process it asked for the credentials into my airport. Thinking it would be a good idea, I gave it to it. First sign that was a bad idea was that it immediately rebooted the AP without any warning it was going to do so. Now the AP locks up every day or so. (might be load related, heavy internet usage days seem to cause it to lock up faster.)

When it locks up:

- the status light remains green
- it falls off the network

  - can't be pinged
  - can't connect to with management tools
  - dns isn't answering
  - dhcp isn't handing out addresses
- no ipv6 tunnel traffic will be routed
- no ipv4 nat'd traffic will be routed

So far, I've only configured a couple services on the server... none of which conflict with the services offered by the AP (DHCP, DNS, etc.)

I'm not seeing any indication of what Server actually changed on my AP, does anyone know how I can undo whatever they did? Or any idea why it might be locking up?

The Airport Extreme is running firmware 7.6.3.
OS/X server version is 2.2.1 (169)

Comment: You know, I was wondering if my Airport instability was due to the recent change where I let my server maintain it as well. I'll try to watch the logs and suggest an answer - even if I am not sure this could be a bug that takes several eyes to nail down. If you edit in the version of Server App and AirPort software, that might help us reproduce or know if we have the same setup.

Comment: After the second reboot of the day, I just disabled every service in Server and changed the base station password on the AP to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: So 2 days without Server being able to manage the AP and all services disabled, no problems. I'm going to re-enable the services and see what that does.

Comment: I've had all the services re-enabled for weeks now, back to being solid as a rock. This coming long holiday weekend, I'm going to risk re-enabling management and see if it starts crashing again.

Comment: If it starts crashing again: "we want log files!"

Comment: I've had similar Airport Extreme problems, seemingly caused when a relative's Android phone is connected to WiFi.